# how to disable specific dates on wix

Tags: javascript, velo

Question 1) How to disable specific dates on WixCode. Using the datePicker, I would like to disable the Dates Starting from Today and > 4 days away.

2) Also to disable all dates from 9 Months away.

I know the standard set disable looks like this:

```
let badDate1 = new Date(2017, 0, 13);
let badDate2 = new Date(2017, 9, 13);
$w("#myDatePicker").disabledDates = [badDate1, badDate2];
```

So how do I accomplish question 1 & 2. Thanks a Mill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, calculate the first and last dates that are enabled using standard JavaScript date functions. Then, use the [minDate](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/$w.DatePicker.html#minDate) and [maxDate](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/$w.DatePicker.html#maxDate) properties of the date picker element.

Something like this:

```
const startFromDays = 4;
const endAtMonths = 9;
const today = new Date();
let startDate = new Date(today);
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 3);
let endDate = new Date(today);
endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 9);

$w.onReady(function () {
    $w("#datePicker").minDate = startDate;
    $w("#datePicker").maxDate = endDate;
});
```

Comment: sorry your answer is confusing and not sufficient

Comment: let me check it out. thanks. will confirm in a moment.

Comment: It Worked. Thanks alot Sam. If i'm stuck again, i hope i can reach you again. thanks.

Comment: Good Evening Sam, please take a look at this. It's a continuation of your answer. i need your expertise please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361758/i-want-to-store-the-value-of-a-datepicker-in-wixcode